# Efficient way for learning proofs

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I do not know, if that is a good question to ask here, but I will give it a try. I just want to ask, whether there is any effective way to learn proofs, because I am struggling with it and I forgot a lot.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I don't think there's any simple method that works for everyone.  Find a good teacher, work a lot of examples, read good texts.

Comment: I'll only comment, because I'm not sure how well this would work. If you learn simple examples of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_proof#Methods) techniques (except the last two or three), you can see how they're each used in proofs you encounter later. That will start your cultivation of pattern-spotting, because proofs do include certain patterns. Maybe that will make remembering them easier.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you ask about learning a proof that is already presented, not finding it. Try to find out the necessary steps, and write them down as compact as possible. This is probably the best way to be able to memorize them.

Comment: @Peter yes, I am. Thanks. So far I'm not far enough to do them by my own and  teachers don't require me to do that. I just want to do my best in learning and understanding them

Comment: @J.G. Thanks I will give it a try